# JasperReports: Converting String into array and populating List with it

Tags: list, jasper-reports

What I have is this `String [125, 154, 749, 215, 785, 1556, 3214, 7985]`
(string can have anything from 1 to 15 ID's in it and the reason it is a string and not a List is that, its being sent through a URL)

I need to populate a List called `campusAndFaculty` with it

**I am using iReport 5.0.0**

I've tried entering this in the `campusAndFaculty` default value Expression field

```
Array.asList(($P{campusAndFacultyString}.substring( 1, ($P{campusAndFacultyString}.length() -2 ))).split("\\s*,\\s*"))
```

But it does not populate the `campusAndFaculty` List

Any idea how I can populate the `List campusAndFaculty` using that `String ("campusAndFacultyString")`?

**======================
UPDATE**

I have these variables in iReport (5.0.0)

```
String campusAndFacultyFromBack = "[111, 125, 126, 4587, 1235, 1259]"

String noBrackets = $P{campusAndFacultyFromBack}.substring(1 ($P{campusAndFacultyFromBack}.length() -1 ))

List campusAndFacultyVar = java.util.Arrays.asList(($V{noBrackets}).split("\\s*,\\s*"))
```

When I print campusAndFacultyVar It returns "[111, 125, 126, 4587, 1235, 1259]"

but when I use it in a Filter I get the "Cannot evaluate the following expression: org_organisation.org_be_id in null"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String something = "[125, 154, 749, 215, 785, 1556, 3214, 7985]";
Arrays.asList((something.substring(1, (something.length() -1 ))).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Which means you can do this in **iReport**:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(($P{campusAndFacultyString}.substring(1, (something.length() -1 ))).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Differences with your snippet:

- It's Arrays, not Array
- You should take 1, not 2 from the length
- Fully qualified reference to Arrays class (which may or may not matter depending on how your iReport is configured)

Comment: I use "java.util.Arrays.asList(($P{campusAndFacultyFromBack}.substring(1, ($P{campusAndFacultyFromBack}.length() -1 ))).split("\\s*,\\s*"))" but It returns as Null

Comment: If I print it then it shows but when i try and use it as a filter it returns null